# Estimating the confidence interval in a convenience sample

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, sampling

So there's a textbook question I stumbled upon:

A marketing research firm estimates the proportion of potential customers preferring a certain brand of lipstick by "randomly" selecting 100 women who come by their booth in a shopping mall. Of the 100 sampled, 54 stated a preference for Brand A.

How would you estimate the true proportion of women preferring Brand A with a confidence interval?

So isn't this a convenience sample? How can we get a confidence interval for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calculating a confidence interval is independent of the method of sampling. The meaning of the confidence interval will be limited, limited to the convenience group, but you can still get a confidence interval the conventional way.

In this case, because it's a binomial distribution there are several potential methods all with their own features. You'll want to check them out on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Confidence_intervals). If you're taking stats the most common method to use is the normal approximation which will just be `p ± 1.96 * sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)`.

If your question was, how do I get a CI that generalizes to the entire population? The answer is that, if you're defining the population as every woman, you don't. However, for the company, the question may be about a very specific population, women who shop in malls (probably malls where the products in question are sold, but that's not specified). In that case, what looks like a convenience sample externally might just be a perfectly fine sample of the population.

Comment: That's not a justification of convenience sample, of course. American Association for Public Opinion Research, the professional organization encompassing researchers and practitioners from hard core mathematical statisticians in Census Bureau to one-day pollsters and market researchers has tried looking into non-probability samples -- see the [report](http://www.aapor.org/AM/Template.cfm?Section=Reports1&Template=/CM/ContentDisplay.cfm&ContentID=5963) published this year which basically failed to give any definitive recommendations (other than that convenience samples are generally terrible).

Comment: ... In particular, it could be a serious mistake to conflate the population of women who show up at a marketer's booth (as described in the question) with the population who actually come to the store (as presumed in this answer).